# Why does my implementation of the CORDIC algorithm only compute the cosine of angles in a small limited interval?

Tags: trigonometry, computer-science, numerical-calculus

I have tried to implement the CORDIC algorithm to compute the cosine, but the interval of angles for which it works is quite limited.

The picture below has been generated by running this C code on the angles in the $[-2.4, 2.4]$ range:

```
float cordic_cos_float(float theta){
    float x = 0.60725293;                   // cosine product
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        
        float d = (z > theta) ? 1 : -1;     // "binary search" direction
        float x_temp = x;
        float pseudotan = powf(2, -i);      // tangent approx
        
        x = x - y * d * pseudotan;
        y = y + x_temp * d * pseudotan;
        z = z - d * my_atan(pseudotan);     // compensates tangent approx
    }
    
    return x;
}
```

The implementation of `my_atan` is irrelevant, since even without compensating for the tangent approximation, the interval in which the algorithm works is exactly the same.

[image: my data]

The function appears to return $-0.169712$ on any angle below $-1.739400$ or above $1.739400$.

Among the things I have tried, which did not work, were:

- Using double point precision
- Increasing the number of steps from 10 to 40

Does anybody have an idea of why this happens?

Comment: Nothing surprizing that CORDIC algorithm works only in a certain range... Besides, could you explain the cryptic second line of your program  "float x = 0.60725293;                   // cosine product" ? What is the origin of this "product" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie At each rotation step, a rotation matrix is premultiplied to the input vector: $R_0...R_n x_0$. If you factor the cosine out of the rotation matrix, you get a product of cosines (of the step angles) times a product of matrices applied to the input vector: $cos(\sigma_0)...cos(\sigma_n) M_0...M_nx_0$. By the approximation of $\tan \sigma_i \sim 2^{-i}$, one can compute the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of the product of cosines, which turns out to be around 0.60725293. The tangent approximation is later compensated for with the atan.

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess my question is more of a "why is it limited, and why exactly is it limited to that very range?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood why, it was quite simple actually. Since the step size halves at each iteration, it converges to some angle, and the angle happens to be $\approx \pm 1.739400$, based on the search direction.

It took me some python visualization to get it, so I'll share it with you:

**The white lines are the attempt vectors, the (barely visible) green line is the goal vector.**

- $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$

[image: pi/3]

- $\theta = 1.739400$ (limit)

[image]

- $\theta > 1.739400$ (does not converge)

[image]